# Cannot access gnome gui screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gnome, lightdm, cuda

I was trying to install NVIDIA CUDA library on Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME installed over it. While installing I encountered some error that says that  `neavuou` must be disabled to carry out installation.

So, solution involved switching to cli mode > <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then stop the service as

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

After installation, I just switched off from cli mode without starting the service again. The display fades away from the screen.

I forced shutdown and restarted. Now, Ubuntu logs into cli only. I tried restarting lightdm, but no luck.